# If Else block is not executing right

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file ...Here, i  hve a variable var which has value say null, so my concern is it is not executing the right if else block

```
if "%var%" NEQ []  goto A 
    ELSE
    (

    echo "##########################################################################"

    )

    :A


        echo ("BATCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"



        )
```

Comment: Read `if /?` and try `if "%var%" NEQ "" ( echo not empty) ELSE (echo empty)`.

Comment: The issue being layout - the positioning of the parentheses is critical. `) else (` must be on the same physical line, and the first `(` on the same physical line as the `if`. The parentheses for the `when true` action are compulsory if you use an `else` clause.

Comment: Your IF statement will always be TRUE.  Those two comparisons will never be equal.  It will

Answer (score 0):

your if else statement does not work because the syntax is incorrect.
cmd says: `The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF`. 
this means that `)` should be followed by `ELSE`.
and `[]` does not mean `null` in batch. use `defined` instead

```
if defined %var% (
echo defined
) ELSE (
echo not defined
)
```